# validate an unzip file before uploading asp.net

Tags: java, asp.net, applet

I am doubt if something like this is possible with asp.net and an application running in the client side:

- the client opens a webpage in which an asp.net upload control is shown
- that page will also open an exe application
- the user will download it and selects a zip file
- the program will check the files in the zip file and probably will remove some invalid files
- the program will then compress the files into a new zip file
- I dont know whether after that process, the new zip file will be interact with the asp.net upload control?

I have heard that probably, if I make a java applet running on asp.net, java applet can verify the files inside a zip and then upload to the server, right?

Comment: What does "the new zip file will be interact with the asp.net upload control" mean?

Comment: I mean the new zip file will be automatically uploaded on the server through the asp.net upload control

Comment: Why do you even show the users the upload control if they're only supposed to upload files created by your .exe thing? Why not upload directly from your code? Also, how does your system support people running, say, OS X or Linux?

Comment: it is: asp.net opening on browse. in order to reduce the traffic to upload on the server, it should be check inside firs

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: The system is probably Windows and OSX. I would like to check the file before uploading. Checking is to verify the file contents. Files are compressed files so they need to be extracted to check. There might be files not following our criteria then we need to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with asp.net but for Silverlight, it does